# Grails mysql bulk delete statement with join

Tags: mysql, sql, grails

Using Grails v2.2.4 and MySQL v5.1, I'm trying to do a bulk delete on one table using a where cause on it's parent table.

Currently, I have a HQL query:

```
delete MemberChild mc where mc.member.id in 
    (select m.id from Member m where m.submissionId = :submissionId)
```

This query works, but the nested select is highly inefficient in my production system due to very large amounts of records in both tables.

I've tried this HQL query instead:

```
delete MemberChild mc where mc.member.submissionId = :submissionId
```

But this produces a syntax error with the generated SQL (appears to the because its missing the alias so doesn't know what to delete):

```
2017-07-14 11:06:39,672 [main] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM MEMBER_CHILD CROSS[*] JOIN MEMBER MEMBER1_ WHERE SUBMISSION_ID=4 "; SQL statement:
delete from member_child cross join member member1_ where submission_id=4 [42000-164]

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute update query; SQL [delete from member_child cross join member member1_ where submission_id=4]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute update query
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ExecuteUpdatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ExecuteUpdatePersistentMethod.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.executeUpdate(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:605)
```

Having done some direct SQL testing and timings, I want to change to running the following SQL statement which I :

```
DELETE FROM MEMBER_CHILD JOIN MEMBER M ON M.ID = MEMBER_ID 
    WHERE M.SUBMISSION_ID = :submissionId
```

If I run this SQL statement (with a valid submissionId value substituted in) in an sql client directly on my database, then it works: member_child record deleted successfully.

If I try to run this SQL update from my Grails application (via SQLQuery.executeUpdate()), then I get the below exception:

```
2017-07-14 07:14:44,820 [main] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM MEMBER_CHILD JOIN[*] MEMBER M ON M.ID = MEMBER_ID WHERE M.SUBMISSION_ID = ? "; SQL statement:
delete from member_child join member m on m.id = member_id where m.submission_id = ? [42000-164]


org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:396)
at org.hibernate.Query$executeUpdate.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
```

Is this a limitation imposed by hibernate? Or is there a way passed this?

Comment: How about this hql - delete MemberChild mc where mc.member.submissionId = :submissionId !

Comment: if  you post your domain classes, that wil help

Comment: Edited the question to include trying that HQL query and its error.

Comment: paste your domain classes which shows the relationship between domains